# Number of sets of queries for the game guess the number?

Tags: algorithm, math

I have asked this problem on math.stackexchange, but I didn't get any answer.

The problem is to solve a two-player number-guessing game. Let the first person be **A** and the second person be **B**. A chooses a number `x` between 1 and an upper limit `n`. **B** gives queries to **A** in form of (L,R) and **A** will answer with Yes/NO if the number exists in the interval (L,R) both inclusive.

**B** will need to ask a set of queries to uniquely determine the number `x`. So the problem is to find the number of such distinct sets of queries such that **B** will be able to uniquely determine `x`, irrespective of what the value of `x`.  **A** returns the answers to the queries as a whole series -- **B** gets the yes/no responses in a batch, only after making *all* of the queries.

For example, let's say `n` is 2.  The sets of possible queries would be,

```
{(1,1)}, 
{(2,2)}, 
{(1,1),(2,2)},
{(1,1),(1,2)},
{(2,2),(1,2)}, 
{(1,1),(2,2),(1,2)}
```

**Question**:  How can I determine which of these query sets will uniquely identify *any* integer that **A** might choose?

I could think was the we need to basically isolate all the possible numbers from 1 to `n` in some way, otherwise it's not possible to uniquely determine the number. But I have no idea what to do with this information.

Comment: The numbers involved are huge. For example, if `n` is 10, then there are 2^55 possible sets of queries. And it's trivial to show that at least 2^45 of those are valid.

Comment: Why in your example of n=2 you do not count the set `{(1,2)}`, making the answer 7?

Comment: @trincot because (1,2) won't help us identify which number. Let's say we give just the query (1,2) so the answer to this query will always be yes but it won't help us guess the number. It could still be 1 or 2.

Comment: But if we may assume B is smart, then why can we not assume that B applies a binary search in their queries? If we cannot assume B is smart, then why exclude that trivial query? Also why would B ever want to query (1,2) then? It should not be present in *any* set then...

Comment: @trincot I don't think you understand the problem. We don't care about where the number is. We only want those sets which would help us isolate each number because anyone of them could be the answer.

Comment: Please explain me why then there is (1,2) in the last set... If you tell me it is redundant in `{(1,2)}` then certainly it is redundant in *combination* with any other query.

Comment: The answer could be either 1 or 2 right. So if we present A with the queries (1,1) and (2,2) we would already know the answer right, but we want to find all such sets and not the minimal set so we can add all other queries even if they are redundant.

Comment: OK, I see. I think the question would be clearer if the example were given for n=3 instead of n=2. Could you do that?

Comment: @trincot I could but it won't be feasible, as I am guessing the number of sets would be high.

Comment: There will be fewer than 63. I would be interested to see which of those 63 count.

Comment: Just because you asked a question on a site where it is on-topic but didn't get an answer, doesn't mean that you should now ask it on a site where it is off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Comment: Indeed, I agree with John: this is unrelated to programming.

Comment: @John I think it is related to programming/algorithms as well as math. So I think it fits

Comment: @aroma I would say more a problem in enumerative combinatorics, although I don't have any very strong feeling about it. You could try brute-force enumeration for n = 2, 3, 4, 5 (after which is will be infeasible) and then consult https://oeis.org/ to see if the sequence has appeared in the literature. Another idea is that it might be easier to count the sets that *fail* to have the given property. With very little evidence, my hunch is that an inclusion-exclusion approach might work for the complement.

Comment: I'm still not clear on the problem.  You're asking for a *set* of queries, but the actual game would work on a *sequence* of queries: it's a tree, with the actual queries depending on the answers to the questions, no?

Comment: @Prune The game *could* be played interactively, with each query being answered, and the optimal next query depending on the previous answers. But in this problem, the game is played in batch mode. B submits a *set* of queries, and then A returns a *set* of answers. So the challenge is to produce a set of queries that uniquely identifies A's number, without knowing any of A's answers until after all of the queries have been submitted.

Comment: Got it.  Now, what is your objective with this question.  The only clear question I see you present to *us* is to count the quantity of query sets.  I assume you need more: that answer is merely the power set (minus the universal interval and null set) of the `n*(n+1)/2` legal intervals.

Comment: @Prune Not all subsets are adequate query sets since not all sets have the property that their answers can specify each element uniquely. It is an interesting question (whether or not Stack Overflow is the ideal site for it)

Comment: Got it; I clarified this in the question.  Now -- you need to identify *all* such query sets, correct?  Simply finding one is not sufficient: the set of all size-1 queries does that trivially.  Or ... do you need to identify the smallest of the query sets?

Comment: No not the smallest. All of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Set #1 to detect a number:**

`1` set with all single pairs: `{{1,1},{2,2},...,{N,N}}`

**Set #2 to detect a number:**

`N` sets with single pairs except one pair: `{{1,1},{2,2},..,{x-1,x-1},{x+1,x+1},..,{N,N}}`

**Pairs that can't help to identify number:**

`N-1` pairs with length 2: `{1,2},{2,3},,{N-1,N}`

`N-2` pairs with length 3: `{1,3},{2,4},,{N-2,N}`

...

`2` pairs with length `N-1`: `{1,N-1},{2,N}`

`1` pairs with length `N`: `{1,N}`

Total number of useless pairs is:

```
K = (N-1) + (N-2) + ... 2 + 1 = N*(N-1)/2
```

Total number of useless sets is:

```
Z = C(K,0) + C(K, 1) + ... + C(K, K) = 2^K
```

**Number of sets of queries**

To find the answer we need to combine all correct sets with all other types of sets.

```
ANSWER = (Number of set #1 + Number of sets #2) * Z = (1 + N) * (2^K)
```

**UDP**: Answer is wrong, see comment below

Comment: You seem to assume that it is necessary to have at least one query with L==R in order to know x. Surely the pairs which you label useless can be used to know x. For instance, the query set that contains all elements of *"N-1 pairs with length 2"* will result in knowing *x*.